# Powershell: Convert email string to valid format for Send-MailMessage cmdlet

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to read in a field in a CSV file that contains multiple email addresses, and then use the Send-MailMessage cmdlet to send to those addresses.  The string of addresses looks like this in the CSV file.

```
john.doe@domain.com;jane.doe@domain.com
```

The valid format to send is:

```
("john.doe@domain.com", "jane.doe@domain.com")
```

Does anyone have a good way of transforming the original string to a valid format?

Thanks again everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell `-Split` operator like such:

```
$emailstring = 'john.doe@domain.com;jane.doe@domain.com';
$emailarray  = $emailstring -split ';';
Send-MailMessage -To $emailarray ... ...;
```

Comment: Thanks Trevor!  I've used the -split operator before.  My head is certainly not where it needs to be...